# Strange behavior of Event Recievers on custom list

Tags: list, custom

I read a bunch of threads on social.msdn regarding issues with Event Recievers on custom lists that fires twice, but I’m not sure this is the current problem I have. I have been using SP Manager and Event Handler Explorer to see if I could find any duplicate event handler registrations, but it’s empty. I’m almost out of any more hair on my head to pull out.

The site/list where the problem occur comes from a SP-Export/SP-Import, some functionality like workflows, webparts and the Event Recievers is deployed thru a feature. The thing is, if I disable the feature which contains the Event Recievers, it is only fired once. ‘

If I enable the feature again, it is fired twice. So it seems that this  Event Recievers is stocked on the custom list, even though the feature is disabled. I have been trying to do some housecleaning on the feature_deactivating method, where I delete any  Event Recievers on the custom list, but it doesn’t seem to do anything.

If I browse through the Event Handler Explorer, the only two EventHandlers I can find on the list is

Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowAutostartEventReceiver, ItemAdded
Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowAutostartEventReceiver, ItemUpdated

And not the one I have been created.

What is going on?

Best regards
Duftstenen

Comment: Was your custom list saved as a template and then reinstantiated?

Comment: Hi Andy, it was exported from the dev site with Export-SPWeb to the production site with an Import-SPWeb

Comment: Well, when exported it might have been exported with the event handler registrations in place - which might explain how you get them running twice - but I don't know why you can't see them.

Comment: Alright, how can i use Export-SPWeb to export a site, where I don't get those "feature based" stuff included. Im not very thrilled to use the Web based export functionality.

Comment: @Duftstenen Have you tried deactivating the features before exporting the site and then import it on another, to see if the problem still occurs?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I ended up with doing one thing, adding the items to a custom contenttype, instead of using the generic "Element". The EventReceiever was then added to only react on that contenttype, having the "Feature activating" to add eventreciever to that specific contenttype. Then I got the right picture in the SP Manager 2010. Somehow that was not visible in SP Manager 2010, when doing that for "Element".

Thanks for any help in this matter!

D.